# How to match URL in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, url

I have found many examples of how to match particular types of URL-s in PHP and other languages. I need to match any URL from my C# application. How to do this? When I talk about URL I talk about links to any sites or to files on sites and subdirectiories and so on.

I have a text like this: "Go to my awsome website http:\www.google.pl\something\blah\?lang=5" or else and I need to get this link from this message. Links can start only with www. too.

Comment: Presumably you meant to use forward slashes because you will never match URLs with backslashes since you are confusing Microsoft\Windows Land and Unix/WWW Land.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need to test your regex to find URLs you can try this resource

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It will test your regex while you're writing it.

In C# you can use regex for example as below:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*");
// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Match m = r.Match(text);
while (m.Success) 
{
   //do things with your matching text 
   m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: +1 : although you forgot to add the @ symbol in front of the string.

Comment: @Rumplin: can you explain the error you get? if i try with gskinner, the regex matches correctly http://www.test.com/ or do you intend th whole string with the '' ?

Comment: you have to look at the actual url, not the one shown. Stackoverflow corrects links... 'h t t p : / / h t t p : / /' without spaces

Answer (score 18):

Microsoft has a nice page of some regular expressions...this is what they say (works pretty good too)

```
^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx#paght000001_commonregularexpressions

Comment: That one does not include the query string behind the url. it stops at the first '=' letter. To fix, just add the single character '=' so it ends like this "....&amp;%\$#_=]*)?$". Also, that regex pattern will not find an url in string. It will only tell you that the string is an url or not. To find it, ommit "^" at the start and "$" at the end. Regex.Matches(text, pattern) should then return all urls in the text.

Comment: Does it include mailto urls?

Comment: this case fails: http://www.example.com:81/path/index.php?query=toto+le+heros#top     It can be corrected with (ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#=_]*)?   It also doesn't work for url containing a username@hostname

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but a good start would be the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class, which will parse the url for you.

Comment: This could be more specific: for example: var myUri = null; Uri.TryCreate(str, UriKind.Absolute, out myVar); and check if myUri changed from null to non-null.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one defined for URL's.

```
^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regx = new Regex("http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a match collection of all matches found within "yourStringThatHasUrlsInIt":

```
var pattern = @"((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([w]{2}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = regex.Matches(yourStringThatHasUrlsInIt);
```

The return will be a "MatchCollection" which you can read more about here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
          //This code return (protocol://)host:port from URL

          //Commented URL's with different protocols. Just uncomment to test.
          //string url = "http://www.contoso.com:8080/letters/readme.html";
          //string url = "ftp://www.contoso.com:8080/letters/readme.html";
          //string url = "l2tp://1.5.8.6:8080/letters/readme.html";
          string url = "l2tp://1.5.8.6:8080/letters/readme.html";

          string host = "";//empty string with host from url
                //protocol, (ip/domain), port
          host = Regex.Match(url, @"^(?<proto>\w+)://+?(?<host>[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)+?(?<port>:\d+)?/", RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150)).Result("${proto}://${host}${port}");
                //(ip/domain):port without protocol. If HTTPS board loading images from HTTP host.
          //host = Regex.Match(url, @"^(?<proto>\w+)://+?(?<host>[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)+?(?<port>:\d+)?/", RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150)).Result("${host}${port}");

          Console.WriteLine("url: "+url+"\nhost: "+host); //display host
```

see https://rextester.com/PVSO54371

Answer (score 0):

u can also use https://github.com/d-kistanov-parc/DotNetUrlPatternMatching

The library allows you to match a URL to a pattern.

How it works:

- an url pattern is split into parts
- each non-empty part is matched with a similar one from the URL.

You can specify a Wildcard * or ~
Where * is any character set within the group (scheme, host, port, path, parameter, fragment)
Where ~ any character set within a group segment (host, path)

Only supply parts of the URL you care about. Parts which are left out will match anything. E.g. if you don’t care about the host, then leave it out.